# Selecting a specific land cover type based on colors in GEE

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, land-cover, land-classification, image-segmentation

I want to select a specific land cover type in a land cover map obtained from the GEE dataset.
Because I know the corresponding hex colour code, I tried the colour code as a condition to filter the wanted land cover type as below.

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('AAFC/ACI')
crop2019 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')).\
     filter(ee.Filter.eq('color','FF9933')).first()
```

I want to see only specific coloured areas from the below map.

[image]

But, an error message comes up.

'**EEException: Expression does not evaluate to an image.**'

So, could you let me know a good way to address this error message or select the specific land cover type based on the colour?

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual issue here. Colors that you see in the map represent values in the `landcover` band. For example, the color for **water** is `3333ff` and the value of pixels that represent water have value `20`. You cannot filter a collection using one color because the color is not an image property, one image can have different colors (values of `landcover` band).

To get a collection in which every image contains only the water pixels as a mask (1 water, 0 not water) you have to do the following:

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('AAFC/ACI')
water = dataset.map(lambda i: i.eq(20).rename('water'))
```